# Convert apache log date format to epoch in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos7

My goal is to convert dates from my apache logs in the format *"12/Nov/2015:23:28:22"* to epoch format. Can this be done using the date command or do I need to parse and extract the information?

Comment: That's a fairly bizarre datetime format, and neither `date` I tried could parse it, although neither were on CentOS 7, but one was the GNU date, which is what I'd imagine CentOS uses.

Comment: I agree. Though this is the format of my apache logs. I'm kind of surprised date doesn't have a way to provide a date with a custom format

date +"%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S" -s "12/Nov/2015:23:28:22"

Comment: Yeah, I know all about having to parse logs with a weird format you're stuck with. :-) I agree, `date` lets you specify the output format, it would be nice if you could specify the input format as well. @EricRenouf offers a nice solution below though to mash the date into a format `date` understands.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems my `date` command wants `-` instead of `/` between the date parts and that to be separated by a space from the time part.  So I used `sed` to do the conversion like so:

```
date -d "$(echo '12/Nov/2015:23:28:22' | sed -e 's,/,-,g' -e 's,:, ,')" +"%s"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the package `dateutils`:

`dateutils.strptime -i "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S" -f "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S" "20170411T172238"`

where `-i` is your input format and `-f` the output format

Answer (score 0):

While @Matthias Leuffen 's https://stackoverflow.com/a/43351684/308851 is promising (it has the input and output formats wrong but w/e), for me the `-S` option for `dateutils.strptime` simply didn't work, it didn't emit the rest of the log just printed a bunch of timestamps, one after the other, an endless stream of digits so I looked after another solution.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.awk/FXrz0VIvz4A/hhjQuu9gx3YJ adds `strptime` support to `awk` (to gawk 4, to be more precise). So you can use https://serverfault.com/a/253232/64874 to change your log into `#` separated and then

`awk -l ./strptime.so -F'#' '{print strftime("%s", strptime($1, "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %Z")) "#" $2 "#" $3}'`

change `$1 $2 $3` as appropriate for you.